# In-memory database class

Tags: javascript

I built this basic in-memory database that can support some basic operations, like SET, GET, DELETE, COUNT, etc. As well as support transactions. Some of the constraints are as follows: GET​,​ SET​,​ DELETE​, and C​OUNT​ should have a runtime of less than O​ (log n),​ if not better (where ​n​ is the number of items in the database). The memory usage shouldn't be doubled for every transaction.

One improvement I was thinking to apply is to use a data structure like `Map()` to store the data -- shouldn't that provide a runtime of O(1) for all basic operations?

I appreciate any advice on how to improve this code.

```
export class Database {

    constructor() {
        this.database = {valuesCount: {}, names: {}};
        this.transactions = [];
    }

    /**
     * Set the name of the database entry
     *
     * @param {string} name The name to set
     * @param {string} value The value to set the name to
     */
    set(name,value) {
        if(this.database.names[name] === undefined) {
            this.updateValueCount(value);
            this.database.names[name] = value;
        } else if(!!this.database.names[name]) {
            if(this.database.names[name] !== value) {
                this.updateValueCountForExistingName(name, value);
                this.database.names[name] = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Update the value count for a new name
     *
     * @param {string} value The value count to update
     */
    updateValueCount(value){
        this.setCountForValue(value);
    }

    /**
     * Update the value count for an existing name
     *
     * @param {string} name The name of the value count to update
     * @param {string} value The value count to update
     */
    updateValueCountForExistingName(name, value){
        this.deleteValuePropertyForName(name);
        this.setCountForValue(value);
    }

    /**
     * Sets the count of a particular value
     *
     * @param {string} value The value to set the count for
     */
    setCountForValue(value) {
        if(!!this.database.valuesCount[value]) {
            this.database.valuesCount[value]++;
        } else {
            this.database.valuesCount[value] = 1;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get the name of the database entry
     *
     * @param {string} name The name to get
     */
    get(name) {
        console.log(!!this.database.names[name] ? this.database.names[name] : null);
    }

    /**
     * Delete entry from database
     *
     * @param {string} name The name to delete
     */
    deleteFromDatabase(name) {
        if(!!this.database.names[name]) {
            this.deleteValuePropertyForName(name);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Counts the number of occurrences val is found in the database
     *
     * @param {string} value The value to count
     */
    count(value) {
        if(!!this.database.valuesCount[value]) {
            console.log(this.database.valuesCount[value]);
        } else {
            console.log(0);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Begins a transaction
     */
    beginTransaction() {
        if(this.transactions.length === 0) {
            this.transactions.push(this.database);
        }
        let shallowCopy = {valuesCount: {...this.database.valuesCount}, names: {...this.database.names}};
        this.transactions.push(shallowCopy);
        this.database = this.transactions[this.transactions.length-1];
    }

    /**
     * Rollback a transaction
     */
    rollback() {
        if(this.transactions.length > 1) {
            this.transactions.pop();
            this.database = this.transactions[this.transactions.length-1];
        } else {
            console.log('TRANSACTION NOT FOUND');
        }
    }

    /**
     * Commit a transaction
     */
    commit() {
        this.database = this.transactions[this.transactions.length-1];
        this.transactions = [];
    }

    /**
     * Delete value property for a particular name
     *
     * @param {string} name The value to delete
     */
    deleteValuePropertyForName(name) {
        this.database.valuesCount[this.database.names[name]]--;
        if(this.database.valuesCount[this.database.names[name]] === 0) {
            delete this.database.valuesCount[this.database.names[name]];
        }

        delete this.database.names[name];
    }

    /**
     * Handle User Input for Various Database Commands
     *
     * @param {string} input User command line input
     * @returns {boolean}
     */
    handleInput(input) {
        const inputRaw = input.split(' ');
        const action = inputRaw[0];
        const arg1 = inputRaw[1];
        const arg2 = inputRaw[2];
        let name = '';
        let value = '';

        switch(action) {
            case 'SET':
                if(!!arg1 && !!arg2) {
                    name = arg1;
                    value = arg2;
                    this.set(name, value);
                } else {
                    console.log('Invalid Input: the SET command must include a name and a value.');
                }
                break;
            case 'GET':
                name = inputRaw[1];

                if(!!name) {
                    this.get(name);
                } else {
                    console.log('Invalid Input: the GET command must include a name.');
                }
                break;
            case 'DELETE':
                name = inputRaw[1];

                if(!!name) {
                    this.deleteFromDatabase(name);
                } else {
                    console.log('Invalid Input: the DELETE command requires a name.');
                }
                break;
            case 'COUNT':
                value = inputRaw[1];

                if(!!value) {
                    this.count(value);
                } else {
                    console.log('Invalid Input: the COUNT command requires a value to count.');
                }
                break;
            case 'BEGIN':
                this.beginTransaction();
                break;
            case 'ROLLBACK':
                this.rollback();
                break;
            case 'COMMIT':
                this.commit();
                break;
            case 'END':
                return true;
            default:
                console.log('Function is not valid.');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A few points, most of these I have applied to your code here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-in-mem-db?file=index.js

**Potential use of Map and O(1) time**

The javascript objects you are currently using are de-facto dictionaries, so it is unlikely you will gain anything here.

**Unnecessary use of !!**

You have used this frequently in your code, in all the places I checked it was unnecessary.

**handleInput argument parsing**

You can tidy this up considerably using array destructuring (see stackblitz for complete example) ie:

```
const [action, ...args] = inputRaw; 
...
const [name, value] = args;
```

**Use logical OR to simplify if..else**

```
 if(!!this.database.valuesCount[value]) {
            console.log(this.database.valuesCount[value]);
        } else {
            console.log(0);
        }
```

can be simplified to:

```
console.log(this.database.valuesCount[value] || 0);
```

Similarly

```
 get(name) {
        console.log(!!this.database.names[name] ? this.database.names[name] : null);
    }
```

can be simplified to:

```
  get(name) {
        console.log(this.database.names[name] || null);
    }
```

**Over complicated logic in set(..) and when updating value counts**

This could definitely be improved but it would also involve refactoring the way you are updating value counts (ideally there wouldn't be two different methods), so I'll leave it at that.

Comment: Hey there, I appreciate your reply. I gave using `Map` some thought and I am not seeing a benefit in terms of usage or performance. Correct me if I'm wrong but current performance with objects is already currently O(1) for GET, SET, DELETE, COUNT, is it not?

Comment: Yep, as I inferred in my answer its already O(1) as using a JavaScript object as you have is pretty much the same as a dictionary or map.

Comment: Thanks for confirming this @wlf. Another question, if I want to write some tests for this code. Would I write unit tests or integration tests? also, for unit tests, what would I test exactly? say if I am testing the `set` function, what am I check for? do I need to assert that the database object contains the properties I passed in?  also, what if the storage property isn't typically accessible?

Comment: If you're writing unit tests, you'll probably need to access the private `database` member. Accessing private members in tests is a controversial subject, but if you want to do it have a look at the PrivateObject class (https://visualstudiomagazine.com/blogs/tool-tracker/2018/08/testing-private-fields.aspx). Otherwise the tests will be more integration like where you set and get to verify results, or set and count etc. IMO don't get too concerned with what type of test they are, just ensure that however you do it there is adequate coverage. PS can you consider accepting my answer above.